# Get the checked table row text value and send to API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When  a specific row is selected, the row text will be get eg the phone no and the message

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    var result = $("tr:has(:checked)")

    if (result.length < 2) {
        alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");
    } else if (result.length > 4) {
        alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
    
    var json = result.map(function () {
        return [$(this).children().slice(1).map(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim()
        }).get()]
    }).get()
  alert(JSON.stringify(json,0,"\t"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <th>select</th> <th>phone no</th> <th>message</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' />
            </td>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td>hi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' />
            </td>
            <td>1234567</td>
            <td>hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type='checkbox' />
            </td>
            <td>4561234</td>
            <td>hey</td>
           
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btn" type="button" label="button" value="send" />
```

Now, i want to send such data to API using php to send out the message.
The API require 2 field

```
   {

   "phone": "examplestring",
   "message": "examplestring"

    }
```

The above table is hard coded so u guys could see better about the setting of my table. My real table use while loop to echo each row of record

```
 <table>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {?>
  <td><input type="text"value="<?php echo $row['phone'] ?>"></td>
   <td><input type="text"value="<?php echo $row['message'] ?>"></td>

    $specific[] = [
                 "phone" => $row["phone"],
                 "message" =>$row["message"]
               ];
    $result = json_encode($specific,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)              
     ];

    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

The variable $result is an array consists of multiple object literals that will be sent to the API to send out the message

So now im trying to send out those message to those phone no which have been checked.But it isnt working. Any idea will be great,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create json object using jquery. Give td with phone number class 'phone' and td with message class 'msg'. Then using jquery, you can extract those details to be pushed in json object. Hope this helps..

```
   <form method="post" action="test.php" id="msgForm">
   <table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
           <th>select</th> <th>phone no</th> <th>message</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='checkbox' />
                </td>
                <td class='phone'>123456</td>
                <td class="msg">hi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='checkbox' />
                </td>
                <td class='phone'>1234567</td>
                <td class="msg">hello</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type='checkbox' />
                </td>
                <td class='phone'>4561234</td>
                <td class="msg">hey</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   <input type="hidden" id="jsonMsgs" name="jsonMsgs" />
    <input id="btn" type="button"  value="send" />
   </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonObj = [];

        $("#btn").on("click", function () {
            var result = $("tr:has(:checked)");

            if (result.length < 2) {
                alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");
            } else if (result.length > 4) {
                alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }

            $.each( result, function(key, value) {
                var field1 = $(this).find('td.phone').text();
                var field2 = $(this).find('td.msg').text();

                var item = {};
                item["phone"] = field1;
                item["message"] = field2;

                jsonObj.push(item);
            });
            console.log(jsonObj);
            alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));

            $("#jsonMsgs").val(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
            $("#msgForm").submit();
        });
    });      
    </script>
```

And test.php could be:

```
<?php     
$json = $_POST["jsonMsgs"];

//var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

$data = json_decode($json, true);


foreach($data as $ind) {
    echo $ind['phone'] . "<br/>";
    echo $ind['message'] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: i can only get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] , desired result is {"phone" : "123456","message":"testing"}.  btw how can i extract the javascript variable that contain the JSON so i can use it in PHP.  Many Thanks

Comment: Check edited answer.  Used JSON.stringify and then used json_Decode in php file.